# iPad Kiosk Mode

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, web-browser

Is there any way that we can set up an iPad to run as a Kiosk for a web application and not be able to access the browser toolbar? I understand Guided Access will help lock down the app but it was more the browser toolbar access i was looking at locking down.

The browser that we are using is Chrome.

Thank you in advance for all your help!

Comment: I think there is a way to block parts of the screen from being tapped in guided access.

Answer (score 2):

According to the documentation and user reviews, [iCab Mobile](http://icab-mobile.de) has a [kiosk mode](https://appadvice.com/appnn/2014/05/internet-taxi-app-icab-mobile-updated-with-kiosk-mode-enhancements-and-more). I used iCab for many years on several card-catalog macOS kiosks in our Library. Worked like a charm.

Disclaimer: I'm a past extremely satisfied user of iCab and have no financial ties to iCab.